# Ag grid vertical scroll issue

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

From backend data is comming in sequence number. Like ID will be generated as 1,2,3,4.....etc. We are displaying latest record on top like 5,4,3,....

Issue is on vertical scroll, we are missing huge number of rows to display in grid. Please let me know any solution for this.

Note: Per second we are receiving 3000 records

code is as follows:

```
var data[];
var columnDefs = [
{headerName: "ID", width: 50},
{headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", width: 150},
{headerName: "Age", field: "age", width: 90}];
var gridOptions = {
enableColResize: true,
debug: true,
rowSelection: 'multiple',
rowDeselection: true,
columnDefs: columnDefs,   
rowModelType: 'infinite', 
paginationPageSize: 100,
cacheOverflowSize: 2,
maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 2,
infiniteInitialRowCount: 1,
maxBlocksInCache: 2};

function setRowData(allOfTheData) {
var dataSource = {
    rowCount: null, 
    getRows: function (params) {
        console.log('asking for ' + params.startRow + ' to ' + params.endRow);

        setTimeout( function() {

            var rowsThisPage = allOfTheData.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);

            var lastRow = -1;
            if (allOfTheData.length <= params.endRow) {
                lastRow = allOfTheData.length;
            }

            params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
        }, 500);
    }
};
     gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
 }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('GET', 'something');
httpRequest.send();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var data= JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        setRowData(data);
    }
};

  setInterval(function(){
 var id=0;
 var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 if(data.length!=0)id=data[0].id;
 var url= "something?id"=+id;
httpRequest.open('GET', url);
httpRequest.send();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var newdata= JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
       gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(0,newdata);
        gridOptions.api.refreshView();

    }
};

 },3000);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u must set "rowBuffer" property

rowBuffer:
The number of rows rendered outside the scrollable viewable area the grid renders. Defaults to 20. Having a buffer means the grid will have rows ready to show as the user slowly scrolls vertically.

[rowBuffer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessibility/)
[rowBuffer Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/)